# Mongoose indexing html text?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, typescript, mongoose

I have a doc with field html. The html field stores real html.

```json
schema: {
  html: String
}
```

```json
doc: {
  "html" : "<p>I am html<p>"
}
```

And I want to index the html field that when I search "I am html" it should return that doc.

Is there any way to search that document only using text inside of that html tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$regex` operator:

```js
db.collection.find({
  "html": {
    "$regex": "I am HTML"
  }
})
```

[Working example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Y6jqkAi2Sak)

Comment: I want to index that as: schema.index({ "html": "text" });

Answer (score 0):

If you have [text index](https://docs.mongodb.com/v5.0/core/index-text/) on this collection, you can search as:

```js
db.collection.find({
  $text: {
    $search: "\"I am html\""
  }
})
```

With double-quotes wrapped, you can search as exact phrase.

> You can also search for exact phrases by wrapping them in double-quotes. If the $search string includes a phrase and individual terms, text search will only match documents that include the phrase.